# Is it possible to alter displayed mail content, but leave original intact via Outlook plugin?

Tags: outlook, vsto, office365, outlook-addin

I am developing an Outlook plugin and one of the features is to alter the visible HTML content of an e-mail viewed in MS Outlook. This alteration, is enabled conditionally via plugin internal state or settings. The problem is that if I rewrite the HTMLBody of a MailItem (on Explorer.SelectionChange, or on MailItem.Open event), the changes are preserved. When I reopen the same item again and the condition is not to alter the mail body, the changes from the previous run are preserved and displayed. While I need to display the original. Storing the previous HTMLBody contents is an option, but I am not 100% sure that restoration will take place in case of Outlook shutdown or crash, for example.

Are there any better options, or at least some good practices on how to alter and restore the MailItem contents consistently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot do that. The best you can do is add a form region that will display its own content or create your own custom form (it will be based on the custom image class) that will show its own UI.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Will try the form region solution.